# RoR collecting from hash and displaying it in html

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I'm trying to retrieve note titles from a specific notebook whenever the user clicks it's link and display them in another column. Please be gentle with me, still a newbie at ruby/rails.

**in my static_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @user = current_user
    @notebooks = @user.notebooks
    @notes_hash = @user.notes.group_by(&:notebook_id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**in my index.html.erb**

```
<div id="notebooks-list">
    <% @notebooks.each do |notebook| %>
        <%= link_to notebook.description, "#", {:class => "notebook-link", 
            :remote => true, :data => notebook.id.to_json }%>
    <% end %>
</div>
<div id="notes-list">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".notebook-link").click(function() {
            var id = this.getAttribute("data");
            <%= notes = @notes_hash['id'] || [ ] %>

            var notes = <%= notes.collect{ |a| a.id }.to_json %>

            $("#notes-list").html(notes);   
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

apparently, im doing something wrong.

Comment: Why are you writing `script` tag inside the `div` you intend to replace?..it will work only first time and next time it will not work as the `script` tag has been replaced.

Comment: thanks, i'm going to edit that now.

EDIT: actually, i tried displaying the var id, even with the javascript inside the div, for some reason it worked for several clicks.

Comment: ok..so what are u trying to display in the div..now you are sending an array of ids of notes record as the content of the div..

Comment: yeah, basically i want to display the notes of the notebook link that was clicked. so what i did was pass the id of the notebook clicked, and i want to lookup that id in the @notes_hash... and im not sure how to go about it.

Comment: why don't you render hidden divs with grouped notes and onClick routine will just show them?

Comment: wow, i think thats a better solution. mind if you can edit your answer and put that in? gonna consider it the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, that's a bad code (

To fix current variant:

first of all <%= notes = @notes_hash['id'] || [ ] %> will output notes value just in script, so fix it to <% notes = @notes_hash['id'] || [ ] %>

Next you initializing notes variable each time you click .notebook-link, so remove it from current routine:

```
<div id="notes-list">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        <% notes = @notes_hash['id'] || [ ] %>
        var notes = <%= notes.collect{ |a| a.id }.to_json %>
        $(".notebook-link").click(function() {
            var id = $(this).getAttribute("data");
            $("#notes-list").html(notes[id]);  # notes[id] is just an object, you will probably wants to render it someway e.g. with JQ templates 
        });
    })()
</script>
```

Another way to do that is just render hidden divs with grouped notes and onClick routine will just show matching div:

```
<div id="notebooks-list">
    <% @notebooks.each do |notebook| %>
        <%= link_to notebook.description, "#", {:class => "notebook-link", 
            :remote => true, :data => notebook.id.to_json }%>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% @notes_hash.each_pair do |nh_id, notes| %>
    <div class="notes-list hidden" data="<%= nh_id %>">
        <ul>
            <% notes.each do |note|
                <li><%= note. description %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".notebook-link").click(function() {
        $(".notes-list").hide().filter("[data=\"" + $(this).attr("data") + "\"]").show()
    });
</script>
```

Comment: figured it was bad code, i liked your other solution though. mind if you can change your answer with that?

Comment: thanks for this! still learning ruby/rails and this helps out a lot!